# What should you know before you study "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" by Tamás Szamuely?

Tags: galois-theory, book-recommendation, fundamental-groups, advice

I am interested in the book "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" by Tamás Szamuely.

I would have to learn some basics, and refresh stuff here and there.
The point of this question is to figure out what you should know before you can seriously understand the book.

Can you use it as an introduction to algebraic geometry, or should you know some algebraic geometry first?
The author writes he assumes as little background as necessary.

Most of the time an author writes this, it turns out to be a lie...

Can you say something about this book?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t think you can expect to learn algebraic geometry per se from this book, because there isn’t actually that much algebraic geometry in it. But you probably need to know the basic definitions, at least up to the definition of étale morphisms but not including sheaf cohomology.

Comment: @ZhenLin My goal would not be to learn algebraic geometry from it, but about Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups. So the question about the algebraic geometry is, if the algebraic geometry needed to study the text is developed purley in the text.

Comment: Well, the definition of scheme, étale morphism, etc. is given in the book. It is very, very brief – the definition of scheme takes less than two pages. I do not think it would be reasonable to expect to be able to learn from this book alone.

Comment: Thanks, so at which stage would you say you can pick this book up and benefit from it?